# Masking date appends extra character in IE8 but works fine in IE11, chrome and other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, datepicker

I have this below function to `mask` the `date` when user types the `date` in the field. I've used `jquery-ui-datepicker` and the strange thing is when `datepicker` is not associated with the field this works as expected.

> **Note - I am getting this problem in IE8 but works fine in IE11, Chrome etc.,**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/9fjkh5sm/)**

**Problem example:** Type 121 in `date` field it should replace it with `12/1` but its placing extra character like `12/11`. Can anyone let me know what's causing this issue:

```
function maskDate(element) {

    var chr = window.event.keyCode
    var str = document.getElementById(element).value

    var lastindex = str.length - 1
    var lastchr = str.charAt(lastindex)

    if (chr < 48 || chr > 57) {
        if (str.length == 1 && (chr == 45 || chr == 47)) {
            document.getElementById(element).value = "0" + str + "/";
            return false;
        }
        if (str.length == 4 && (chr == 45 || chr == 47)) {
            document.getElementById(element).value = str.substr(0, lastindex) + "0" + lastchr + "/";
            return false;
        }
        if (chr == 47 && (str.length == 2 || str.length == 5)) return true;
        else {
            if (chr == 45 && (str.length == 2 || str.length == 5))
                document.getElementById(element).value = str + "/";
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (str.length == 2 || str.length == 5) {
            document.getElementById(element).value = str + "/" + String.fromCharCode(chr);
            return false;
        }
        if (str.length > 9) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

Just placed a debugger and noted that

```
document.getElementById(element).value = str + "/" + String.fromCharCode(chr);
```

in the above line the value of `document.getElementById(element).value` is getting set properly but then I am not getting where the extra value is getting set because the control is getting passed to `jquery.js` after return false which makes complicated to understand the exact flow then!

Comment: *"but works fine in IE11, chrome and other browsers"* Not in Firefox, I'll guarantee you that. Firefox doesn't support `window.event`.

Comment: Even IE8 has F12 Dev Tools. Your best bet for figuring this out is to use them to debug the code.

Comment: Not a problem @T.J.Crowder. I am concentrating on making it work on IE8

Comment: Yea, right. I'll take that suggestion.

Comment: Just to clarify, all it does is allow only 8 digits (any) and put those slashes in at the right place. Isn't it?

Comment: @LShetty.. Exactly!!